# Axios not responsive at all, React Native with Django backend

Tags: reactjs, django, react-native, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a post request to a django-based REST API inside an RN project with an Axios post request.

I am getting no network error messages, no crash, no errors no whatsoever. I tried the same code on an Expo project and I was facing the same reaction (no reaction).

I already did all required steps (like using the IP address instead of localhost) for making Django local-host development-friendly:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Also

```
'rest_framework',
'corsheaders',
```

as well as

```
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
```

I installed the latest packages for Axios, RN.
The server is not receiving any requests at all too. So my initial guess is there is something blocking like an SSL issue or some kind of internal-error/loop. Disabled the firewall too, and you can guess the scenario.

Comment: Is your request going through the curl command or any other API tool like the postman? The first step to debug this should be to try from these options and then drill down whether the network is the culprit or the code.

Comment: I second the above, and the obvious one if you're using http instead of https that is an issue if you havent previously addressed it in the configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging in my older projects I finally found out the solution which is pretty simple.
Changing the IP address inside the react native requests is not enough, the Django server as well needs to be informed about which host and port to be run through initiating the command: `python manage.py runserver <host:port>`.

The host is equivalent to our IP address, (e.g., 192.168.x.x) and the port is usually 8000.

Answer (score 0):

Yes from this method i have solved my issue.
**HERE is code**
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [

```
"http://localhost:3000",
'http://your pc ip4 :8000'
```

]
**Run servser: python manage.py runserver your pc ip4:8000**

**AND**
**ON React native side**
you write this code **let response = await axios.post('http://your pc ip4:8000/Your endpoints'**